# Is it possible to set line spacing to negative values (shrinking)?

Tags: line-spacing

I'd like to shrink a document and use slightly negative line spacing values. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Note that I'd like to use negative line spacing. So i'd like to shrink the document and have lines that possibly overlap. Usual commands like `baselinestretch` or `baselineskip` do not help here as they use positive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you please have a look at the following code?

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\baselineskip}{8pt}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-4pt}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\baselineskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-6pt}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\baselineskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-8pt}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That answers the question, and I learned something new. Apparently the trick is in the `\lineskiplimit` commands. Incidentally, I compiled using LuaLaTeX, but I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks! That lineskiplimit made it work! I've tried your MWE and it worked perfectly. However, it seems that within the multicolumn environment it doesn't seem to work so well - I'll have to look into that.

Comment: Please, if someone can add explanation to the answer :). I am one of those which staggered at the effectiveness of modifying `\lineskiplimit`. I have been testing around with `\baselineskip` and `\linespread` alone without success, and just this simple command `\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{x}` made it work. Thank God!